# Flutter: How to fix accessibility focus on landscape mode?

Tags: android, flutter, accessibility

I'm struggling with an accessibility issue on a project which i'm working on.
I can't show you the code because the project is under NDA, but fortunately (or not) the issue is replicable on the Flutter template project (the counter one).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Youtube video of the issue](https://youtu.be/Wt4uBF_h61c)

When the app is in portrait mode, the TalkBack and the accessibility focus work as expected. (image 1 and 2)

Instead, on landscape mode, the TalkBack work as expected, but the accessibility focus has a left padding. In this way, the green box doesn't wrap correctly the components and often the double tap gesture doesn't work on the FAB. (image 3, 4 and video).

This is the output of `flutter doctor` command:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-IT)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Do you know how is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Not sure about flutter code but can you try putting something like
android:importantForAccessibility="yes" for the UI items.

Comment: @prashant in this case the UI is not made with native view (PlatformView), so i can't specify tags in that way

Comment: FYI this is a Flutter's issue. I opened a issue on the Flutter's Github
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102725